# Your app has not been accepted into Designed for Families, and the update is not live on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

**Eligibility issues:**

**Generic DFF eligibility**
The family-friendly experience on Designed for Families is intended to make apps easier to discover for parents and families, who expect the apps to be age appropriate. After careful consideration we have determined that your app does not meet our eligibility criteria. Apps in the program must be specifically designed for children, have a rating of E or E10+, and include relevant app information.

**Next Steps:**

Make the necessary changes to your app.
Submit your app for another review.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: We're not Google, so we can't review your app. We don't even know what it is or what it does.

Comment: i can't upload my app, in app kids can learn english language. I created it by using Youtube API

Answer (score 0):

Your application is not designed for Families according to Google. You have to go to your application in the console, on the left you will see "Store Presence" scroll to "Pricing & Distribution", scroll down to "User programs" there you will find "Designed for Families", uncheck that and you should be good to go. It may take a few hours to be approved by Google.[image: Designed for Families]

The other option is following the [Designed for Families guideline](https://play.google.com/about/families/?visit_id=636766964327531146-2720653676&rd=1) and resubmit your application.

Hope this helps, not sure what you were asking.